Why is My MongoDB Query Returning Null Even Though the Document Exists?
I am encountering an issue with querying a MongoDB database using Mongoose in a Node.js application. Despite having valid data in the database, the query returns null. Here’s a detailed account of the problem, including code snippets and sample data.
Problem Statement:
When executing a query to find a document by its _id in a MongoDB collection, the result is null even though the document with the specified _id exists in the database. This issue persists despite verifying that the data is correctly stored and accessible via direct queries to MongoDB Atlas.
Sample Data:
Below is a sample dataset stored in the MongoDB collection:
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('66c8d4d59112cf429d9b49c3'),
    name: 'Angle Cock',
    description: 'Used to control water flow at a 90-degree angle.',
    images: 'https://rukminim2.flixcart.com/image/416/416/xif0q/faucet/9/6/t/wall-mount-installation-type-polo-pvc-angle-cock-white-pack-of-1-original-imahfgxagpc3abed.jpeg?q=70&crop=false',
    brand: 'Brand A',
    availability: true,
    price: 15.99,
    category: 'Taps',
    ratings: 4.5
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('66c8d4d59112cf429d9b49c4'),
    name: 'Pillar Cock',
    description: 'Standard tap for sinks or basins, often found in bathrooms.',
    images: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSAIiSTRJ6gqst2qK-60PMcAjasYr6y-H9xQ&s',
    brand: 'Brand B',
    availability: true,
    price: 12.99,
    category: 'Taps',
    ratings: 4.3
  }
]

Problematic Code:
Here’s the code snippet that is intended to query the document by its _id:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.getOneProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Extract the product ID from the request parameters
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(`Product ID: ${id}`);

    // Ensure the ID is a valid MongoDB ObjectId format (even if it's a string)
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid product ID" });
    }

    // Find the product by its ID, as a string
    const product = await Products.find({ _id: id });
    console.log(`Product Found: ${JSON.stringify(product)}`);

    // Check if the product was found
    if (!product) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found" });
    }

    // Return the product in the response
    res.status(200).json({ result: product });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the process
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};

If I try with name instead of id it is working see the below output :
Searched with name instead of Id
But it works fine in terminal operation
Atlas atlas-s7qbvh-shard-0 [primary] E-Commerce> db.products.find({_id:"66c8d4d59112cf429d9b49c3"})
[
  {
    _id: '66c8d4d59112cf429d9b49c3',
    name: 'Angle Cock',
    description: 'Used to control water flow at a 90-degree angle.',
    images: 'https://rukminim2.flixcart.com/image/416/416/xif0q/faucet/9/6/t/wall-mount-installation-type-polo-pvc-angle-cock-white-pack-of-1-original-imahfgxagpc3abed.jpeg?q=70&crop=false',
    brand: 'Brand A',
    availability: true,
    price: 15.99,
    category: 'Taps',
    ratings: 4.5
  }
]

Despite multiple attempts to resolve this issue, including reviewing various solutions , Eg : mongo always returns null even though data is available and exploring different AI tools, I am unable to get the code to return the document correctly. I would greatly appreciate any help in diagnosing and fixing this issue.

Did you tried with Products.find({ _id: mongoose.ObjectId(id) }); ?

@YuvarajM I tried the following and i am getting this error
const products = await Products.find({ _id: mongoose.ObjectId(id) });
console.log(products);
TypeError: this.splitPath is not a function
at Mongoose.SchemaType (C:\Users\dbdhu\OneDrive\Desktop\b\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:55:8)
at Mongoose.SchemaObjectId [as ObjectId] (C:\Users\dbdhu\OneDrive\Desktop\b\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectId.js:36:14)
at exports.getOneProduct (C:\Users\dbdhu\OneDrive\Desktop\b\Backend\controllers\common\productController.js:25:28)

@RobertMoskal Heatful Thanks i have now got fixed the issue.
